# Pass an array along when a contract creates a new contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses, arrays

Can an array be passed along as a contract creates a new contract ? Specifically, an array of addresses.

```
address[] verifiedUsers;


new generatePOItokens(verifiedUsers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Here's an example, assuming 2 addresses:

```
contract C {
  address[] public verifiedUsers;
  function C(address[] addr) {
    verifiedUsers.push(addr[0]);
    verifiedUsers.push(addr[1]);
  }
}

contract D {
    address[] addr;
    address cAddr;
    function D() {
        addr.push(0xa);
        addr.push(0xb);
        cAddr = new C(addr);
    }

    function getCaddresses(uint index) returns(address) {
        return C(cAddr).verifiedUsers(index);
    }
}
```

In [Solidity Browser](https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity), enter the code above, then click Create for D.
Click on `getCaddresses` with either a value of 0 and 1 and you'll see the corresponding stored address.